# How application deployed on elasticbeanstalk access files created by another application running on ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application(A) deployed on amazon aws using elasticbeanstalk. I also have another multi threaded java application(B), which creates some file on periodic basis, which needs to be read/updated by the application(A) running on elasticbeanstalk.

If i directly run the application (B) on EC2 then Application (A) does not have access to it.

What model should i use in this situation so that Application (A) can access files created by application(B).?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the files created by *B* to S3, you can do this with the AWS api or use S3 Fuse to mount it in the filesystem.  Then have *A* read them the same way with either the API or S3 Fuse.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Is there any way Application(A) can access files directly from EC2 folder?. As the files are being updated on continuous basis and we want Application(A) to have access to it.

Comment: You could access them with the AWS sdk, however the data on those ec2 instances is ephemeral meaning they can and will go away at any time.  You want storage that is permanent, you could also try Elastic File System, or mounting an EBS volume.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Will use AWS sdk.

Comment: @user2848853 Using the AWS sdk is hardest way to accomplish your task but if you are going to do it that way please also use a mounted EBS volume to store the data from A.

Comment: I have also applied for preview version of Elastic file system - which allows for 2 applications to access the file system. Its not available in all regions yet.

Comment: It seems like your situation would be handled better by a database, what are you storing in these files?

Comment: Stefan - These are lucene index files, which we are using for our search algorithm.